# Swift iOS - passing dictionary object to detail view

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, swift, option-type

I'm playing around with the Master-Detail iOS project in Xcode6.01 and Swift. I have a simple data entry screen that adds swift dictionary objects to a Swift datasource array for the table.

The data entry and table view work fine. I've run into this problem when tapping on a cell, extracting a dictionary object from the array and trying to pass that dict object along to the detail view.

The configureView() function in the detail view is causing an exception. Here's the code:

```
func configureView() {

 if let dictObject:Dictionary = detailItem as? Dictionary<String,String> {

  if var strName = dictObject["name"] {

   // prints fine:
   println(strName)

   // fatal error
   self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = strName

   // debug output:
   // prints the string in strName (no mention of optional)
   // assigning to label:
   // fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

  }

 }

}
```

It seems strange that the println() statement has no problem with the strName variable and there is no mention of it being an optional in the output panel. As soon as it tries to assign the string to the label, bang - crash.

Comment: May it be that the error is related to `self.detailDescriptionLabel` which may be an optional?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer my self. It was not the dictionary object that was nil, but the labels in the view!

After adjusting the code with an IF LET construct for the labels it works like this:

```
func configureView() {

 if let dictObject:Dictionary = detailItem as? Dictionary<String,String> {

  if let dLabel = detailDescriptionLabel {

   dLabel.text = dictObject["name"]

   }

   if let eLabel = emailLabel {

    eLabel.text = dictObject["email"]
   }

 }
}
```

I must admit though, I don't know why this is needed. I thought the storyboard would init the labels. The labels in question are regular IBOutlets:

```
@IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!
```